# How do I configure a dependency in a gradle project such that it also works as a submodule?

Tags: gradle, git-submodules

I want to use a project in my project as a git submodule, ideally without changing the upstream project (or if it makes sense, changing it in a way that will get merged there).

The problem is that the project consists of modules, 2 of which I want to directly use, with the one also depending on the other.

```
myProject
├ submodule
| ├ first
| | ├ build.gradle: implementation project(":second") <---- this fails if I don't change it to :submodule:second
| ├ second
| ├ settings.gradle: include ':first', ':second'
├ app
| ├ build.gradle: implementation project(":submodule:first"), implementation project(":submodule:second")
| ├ settings.gradle: include ':submodule:first', ':submodule:second', ':app'
```

As my project's `settings.gradle` replaces the submodule's `settings.gradle`, the submodule's absolute paths suddenly change. Can I somehow `include ':submodule:second as :second'?

I know I can use `implementation project(somePrefix + ":second")` and define this `somePrefix` accordingly but that would involve touching the submodule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle project paths (e.g. `':submodule:second'`)

- actually represent project hierarchies. This means that using `include ':submodule:second'` in your `settings.gradle` will implicitly create a project called `submodule`, even if not relevant for the build at all.
- do not need to match the directory structure (this is just a convention). You may set the project directory independent from the project path (and the project name).

Check out the following example from [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html#org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings:include(java.lang.String%5B%5D)):

```
// include two projects, 'foo' and 'foo:bar'
// directories are inferred by replacing ':' with '/'
include 'foo:bar'

// include one project whose project dir does not match the logical project path
include 'baz'
project(':baz').projectDir = file('foo/baz')
```

---

However, I would recommend to not use `include` at all. Instead use `includeBuild` and setup a [composite build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html). Composite builds differ from classical multi-project builds in their coupling. Since your Git submodule indicates a build that may be used as a standalone project (with its own `settings.gradle`), the strong coupling of a multi-project builds seems inappropriate. Multiple `settings.gradle` files may also cause problems in a multi-project build, but are fine for composite builds.

Comment: Thank you Lukas! I will investigate the `includeBuild` feature, too but suspect I prefer the control the `include` gives me. The submodule contains 4 modules of which we only use 2, so why compile 4 and have to deal with the side effects if we only need 2?

Comment: I don't think the other modules will be compiled using composite builds. You may still express project dependencies and Gradle will only execute the tasks necessary to build the required artifacts.